# Visual proof for $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$

Tags: visualization

I've found visualizations of simple mathematical concepts to be a really useful tool in building intuition for more complex mathematical concepts. For example, [this visualization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3321341/460691) of $(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$ can be used to visualize the [calculus product rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG15m2VwSjA).

That being said, does anyone know of a visual way to show the following equation?
$$
\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}
$$

Comment: you can use the same visualization? after all $\frac a b = ab^{-1}$ and $\frac c d = cd^{-1}$

Comment: Yep, divide through by $bd$ in your visualisation. Even better, re-draw or re-label each relevant quantity in your visualisation (in effect, dividing by $bd$), so that your second equation is visualised

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, these would basically just be using the rectangles to visualize distributivity? That does work, but IMO it feels a lot less elegant than the other proof. Maybe my question is unreasonable though, and there just isn't a better way to look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

> [image]

See also this one: https://www.geogebra.org/m/DV6Ehjnx#material/aEsvBzN2

Comment: I really like this, thank you! It feels like I'm going back to elementary school :').

Comment: Yes, this is the way we teach elementary school teachers to teach (but most of them don't). But isn't this exactly what @BenjaminWang suggested above?

Comment: @Frank: you are welcome!

Comment: TedShifrin: well, I think the picture is a "visualization" literally... :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Visualization of sum of two quotients]

This image is intended to show that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$.
The width of this cuboid can be computed in two ways, one way by simple addition.
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$$
Another way is to compute the volume of the cuboid first. The volume of the green cuboid is the area $a$ times the depth $d$, the volume of the blue cuboid is the area $c$ times the height $b$. Adding these volumes gives $ad+bc$. Therefore the width of this cuboid is the volume of the cuboid divided by the height $b$ and depth $d$.
$$\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version which depends on similar triangles.

[image]